# liquid simulation to follow Smoke simulation using Guides setting

Tags: smoke-simulation

[image]

I am trying this video But when I turn on Guides of Liquid Domain, flow disappears. How should I fix this??
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldUwslQJ9NQ

Blend file is this.[image]